# What is the standard way for dealing with PowerPoint (.PPTX) files on the server?

Tags: c#, .net, powerpoint

I've been tasked with a feature that can generate PowerPoint files on the server using C#.  I'd  basically start with a template, and programmatically *replace* some text with live data from the database.  I've been doing some research into this area for the past day and here's what I've found:

PowerPoint has this sort of thing built in, meaning it can connect to external data sources and pull in data.  Most examples of this, I've found, either use PowerPoint automation done on the server (I've been advised against this) or assume a SQL Server backend.  Our company uses Oracle for our RDMS needs.  Oracle has a solution for this called Oracle BI, but it requires a whole new web server setup to run various Java EE components and what not.  I didn't look at the price, but knowing Oracle it's not cheap.  It also requires new software to be installed on the end user's machine, which we *really* want to avoid.

Generating PowerPoint files on the fly is possible.  The company that is basically the go-to guys for this problem (every help forum points to them, and they get all the rave reviews) is [Aspose](http://www.aspose.com/.net/total-component.aspx).  They have .NET components for dealing with just about any Office format you can think of.  The problem is, they are astronomically expensive.  Just the PowerPoint component (a site license for up to 10 developers) would cost $3,995.

The third possibility is generating a solution in-house.  After all, a PPTX file is just xml, right?  Well, looking closer, a PPTX appears to be a gzip archive.  It contains many folders, each containing many XML files.  Modifying a PPTX file would, correct me if I'm wrong, entail unzipping the file to a temporary directory, reading the XML file and modifying the contents, then packaging up everything again and write the file out to the response stream.  Perhaps there are libraries that can work with gzip streams on the fly without extracting everything.

**My Question:** Are there easier ways to work with a PPTX file using .NET that don't require working with compressed XML files or buying very expensive software?  Basically, we need to *modify* a PowerPoint file, change some text, and allow the user to download that generated file from a web server.

Comment: You could have an office install on the server, use the interop components to do this, but .... i don't know about the licensing scheme for that which might turn out to be a no-go again.

Comment: Yea I'm quite certain our IT guys will never go for installing Office on our web servers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[OpenXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx) is Microsoft's .Net library that lets you manipulate Office documents.  It lets you open a PPTX file and provides an object model that wraps the XML contents.

Here's the link to the [OpenXML SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425) and the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx).

I've used OpenXML to let a ASP.Net page dynamically generate Word documents from a database.

Comment: Oh I did run across this from other StackOverflow questions, however they were all written in 2009 and pointed to MSDN articles that no longer exist.

Comment: I've added the MSDN links.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use Office Interop on a web server. It's an all-around bad idea.

If you are *only* replacing text placeholders for files that will not change, the home grown solution that finds the placeholders in the xml files in the gzip archive should be doable. .Net has had zip support for some time, and it is greatly improved if you are able to use .Net 4.5, so you shouldn't need to extract the archive to a temporary location at all.

PowerPoint should also support connecting directly to Oracle in the same way it supports connecting to Sql Server (just play around with the connection options), without needing the special Oracle BI stuff. However, I'd still prefer the home-grown solution, as this will only work while the powerpoint file is able to reach your database directly, which is typically only possible in your local LAN environment or with an active VPN.

If you want anything fancier than a simple text replacement, perhaps looks for an Aspose competitor.

Comment: We did try to get Excel to connect with Oracle once, but we had to install Oracle ODBC drivers.  This requires local admin rights to the machine, which no one at this company has.  This means IT would have to push those drivers out, which is a no-go.  Our IT dept is like something out of a Dilbert cartoon.